# How do i solve this error when installing scikit-image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image

I get the below error when using pip install scikit-image. Note I have got Microsoft VS installed.
What is causing this?
not sure if it is an issue with numpy?
Thanks

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\student\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2dp2c1cs\\scikit-image_610bd9ad5a3b4de0a232ce6491f9d39a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2dp2c1cs\\scikit-image_610bd9ad5a3b4de0a232ce6491f9d39a\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r78qb75l\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\student\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\scikit-image'
     cwd: C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2dp2c1cs\scikit-
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\student\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2dp2c1cs\\scikit-image_610bd9ad5a3b4de0a232ce6491f9d39a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2dp2c1cs\\scikit-image_610bd9ad5a3b4de0a232ce6491f9d39a\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r78qb75l\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\student\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\scikit-image' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Could you provide more details? What command did you run to install? Are you in a virtual env? what python versione? OS? etc...

Comment: Hi, I initially ran 'pip install scikit-image' in command prompt. Windows 10. Python 3.9. No virtual environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18621) on GitHub, it is still not available on `Python 3.9`.

They provide a few solutions:

- `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn` with Conda
- `pip install --pre -U scikit-learn` on windows

Answer (score 0):

For python==3.10.4:
Just upgrade your pip command in your CMD as administrator, and everything will work fine.

```
python -m pip install –-upgrade pip
```